# sending image on client side takes too much time in django

Tags: python, django, image

I am storing images as base64 string in database(MYSQL) and then when requested from client side(HTML webpages simply), sending base64 strings of images along with some other data from tables and then embedding this data in img tag  on client side. These tags are built on dynamically using javascript. But this approach takes a lot of time even for 2 images. I see that when serving static images, django serves quite fast.
So what could be a good approach to reduce the time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storing your images in database to serve them on a page is not a good idea.
Upload them to a CDN , and store the URLs in your database.

Comment: That may be a good approach but for now the database is there with above mentioned schema. Do you see any approach to reduce time with given circumstances?